# map function not working for API data in useEffect - React Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

The code below is not populating the UL with any items.  The only item populated is the "Default LI" that I manually put in there.  The console output shows data in response.data.  All of the console.log calls show output, so everything appears to be firing.  Probably something really simple.  Any help appreciated.  Thanks!

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

export default function AssetTypes() {
  const [data, setData] = useState({ items: [] });

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("inside useEffect");
    let url = `https://localhost:5001/api/AssetTypes?organizationId=999`;
    console.log(url);

    console.log("useEffect 1");
    const fetchData = async () => {
      console.log("fetchData 1");
      const response = await axios.get(url);
      console.log("fetchData 2");
      console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
      console.log("fetchData 3");
      setData(response.data);
      console.log("fetchData 4");
    };
    console.log("useEffect 2");
    fetchData();
    console.log("useEffect 3");
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Asset Types</h1>
      <ul>
        <li>Default LI</li>
        {data &&
          data.items &&
          data.items.map((item) => (
            <li key={item.assetTypeId}>
              <span>
                {item.assetTypeName} - {item.assetCategory}
              </span>
            </li>
          ))}
      </ul>
    </>
  );
}
```

Stringify output:

> [{"assetTypeId":2,"organizationId":0,"assetTypeName":"Book","assetCategory":"Book"},{"assetTypeId":4,"organizationId":0,"assetTypeName":"eBook","assetCategory":"Digital"},{"assetTypeId":6,"organizationId":0,"assetTypeName":"Magazine","assetCategory":"Periodical"},{"assetTypeId":8,"organizationId":0,"assetTypeName":"Newspaper","assetCategory":"Periodical"},{"assetTypeId":9,"organizationId":0,"assetTypeName":"Encyclopedia","assetCategory":"Book"}]

Comment: If you're calling `setData` with exactly what you show here, it looks like the data *is* the array and there is no `items` property in it to iterate over.

Comment: Like I said, something simple!  So I guess I'm not sure what to iterate over.  The API doesn't return a "root node" like "items".  So what should that look like?  Is the initialization of useState done the right way for this use case?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Chris Farmer.  Here are the changes I made.  It was something stupid, just as expected!

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]);

...    

{data &&
          data.map((item) => (
            <li key={item.assetTypeId}>
              <span>
                {item.assetTypeName} - {item.assetCategory}
              </span>
            </li>
          ))}
```